# Python3 Print Everything Between "ENC[PKCS7" and "]"

Tags: python, string, file, text

I'm working on grabbing two hashes from the output of a command. Both hashes start with ENC[BKSC8 and in in ] Both hashes are displayed during the output of the command. But they are displayed in a different format. The command Output looks like the following. This is just an example hash:

```
string: ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdf;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfd]

OR

block: >
    ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkal
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    asdlad;fljasd;lfjasdjfl;kjal]
```

I've tried putting the command output into a loop and splitting the strings and but because of the way the command output is formatted this does not work.

```
cmd = "my encryption command --BKSC8 my-file" (Just command example)
output = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)

for line in subprocess.getoutput(cmd).splitlines():
    if "[" and "]" in line:
        print(line)
```

I'm trying to get the two hashes output in the same format. But just the two hashes. Like the following and keeping the same format.

```
string: ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdf;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfl;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkajsdl;fjal;sdkjfajsfalsdfd]

OR

block: >
    ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkal
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    asdlad;fljasd;lfjasdjfl;kjal]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using regex patterns?  I would need to know more about what else could come out from the command output, but this pattern seems to work for the example you've provided.

`hashes = re.findall(r"ENC\[BKSC8[^\[]+\]",text)`, where `text` is the output from the command.  `hashes` is a list containing the hashes.  Example:

```
import re

text = """
Junk
not stuff we want
faksdfjaksdlfjasdk;jf
123412341234
ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkal
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    asdlad;fljasd;lfjasdjfl;kjal]
more junk
more junk
block: >
    ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkal
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    asdlad;fljasd;lfjasdjfl;kjal]
"""

hashes = re.findall(r"ENC\[BKSC8[^\[]+\]",text)
for hash in hashes:
    print(hash)
    print("------------------")
```

produces the following output:

```
ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkal
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    asdlad;fljasd;lfjasdjfl;kjal]
------------------
ENC[BKSC8,l;kasjdfj;asldkfa;sdfja;dsjf;ajdskfjaksdfa;sldjfkal
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    ;alsdjf;lasdjfljdlf;alsdfja;lsdfj;alsdjf;alsdkjf;laskdjf;lak
    asdlad;fljasd;lfjasdjfl;kjal]
------------------
```

Comment: yes! this is exactly what I was looking for! Now after I've gotten the two hashes output can I somehow import both hashes into a dictionary or something like a list for later? I would need the second hash to be called in the same format that it's currently at. Because when I copy the has to my file it needs to stay in that same format.

Comment: The hashes are stored as strings in the `hashes` list when this line executes `hashes = re.findall(r"ENC\[PKCS7[^\[]+\]",text)`, so you can call them later from there.  They should both stay in the same format (the second one is fine as well because the newline characters are stored in the string)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out with this! This was the exact answer I was looking for. Can't thank you enough. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Jacob Rodal suggested was perfect for what I was trying to do. I was able to store both hashes using the re module and the command Jacob suggested.